# Hyper-V Enhanced Session. Cannot share disk between Ubuntu and Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, virtual-machine, remote-desktop, hyper-v

I am struggling to share the disks between my windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS VM.

I have found two articles on a disk sharing with the Enhanced Session remote desktop:

[official: Use local resources on Hyper-V virtual machine with VMConnect](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/virtualization/hyper-v/learn-more/use-local-resources-on-hyper-v-virtual-machine-with-vmconnect)

[tutorial: Using Enhanced Mode Ubuntu 18.04 for Hyper-V on Windows 10](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/UsingEnhancedModeUbuntu1804ForHyperVOnWindows10.aspx)

I did everything like described in the official article but the ubuntu 'shared-disks' folder is empty.

- I have checked command "VMConnect.exe localhost  Ubuntu /edit" And all drives are checked.

[image]

- 'Remote Desktop Services' are running!

[image]

What I am missing here?

I have tried with the C:\ SSD drive and usb flash drive D:\
[image]
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu, IIRC, cannot access D[ynamic Disks](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/basic-and-dynamic-disks), so if the drive you are trying to access is so formatted, it will fail.

Comment: Could you please check the new pic? I have added flash drive FAT but the problem remains.

Comment: C: is not available but D: drive appears but with a delay of 1 minute or so, so problem partially gone, thanks.